# Adding dbFailOnError to CurrentDb.Execute fails to update table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, odbc

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I have a mySQL table connected to Access 2010 via the 5.1 ODBC driver. I am trying to update the mySQL table and curiously adding dbFailOnError at the end of CurrentDb.Execute strSQL prevents the table from updating but does not throw any error. My VBA editor is set to break on all errors. All error handling in the routine has been commented for testing.

If I use **CurrentDb.Execute strSQL** or **DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL**, the table updates. Also, the mySQL table has an index.

SQL string:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE clients
SET [DateLastAccessed] = " & lngDateAccessed & ",
[CountAccess] = " & intCountAccessed & "
WHERE [SerialHDD] = '" & strGetHDD & "' ;"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As you are building the SQL statement in VBA, why not then execute via ADO rather than DAO?

Comment: Does it work if you leave out the date update? Do you have a primary key?

Answer (score 2):

"*adding `dbFailOnError` at the end of `CurrentDb.Execute strSQL` prevents the table from updating but does not throw any error*"

That could fail to update without a visible error if `SetWarnings` has been switched off.  Check whether you get a different outcome when switching `SetWarnings` on immediately before executing the update statement.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```