# Currentdb.Execute with dbFailonError not throwing an error

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

In Access 2003-2016, I am using CurrentDb.Execute with dbFailonError to run an INSERT statement.  The INSERT statement should fail (and it does) because one field has an incorrect value based on a related table with "Enforced Referential Integrity".  However, it does not throw an error.  I have tried recreating this issue in a new database, and the error works correctly.  There is something wrong in the settings with my current database, and I don't want to recreate it from scratch.  I have taken everything out of my database except for the problematic piece, and my [minimal reproducible example database is at this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cTPEzOjMxb2e7ixsWIPIFJNql-XP-IWG/view?usp=sharing).

Here is my code, but the problem is that this code works fine and does throw errors when I create a new database from scratch.  It just doesn't work in my current database.

```
Private Sub Command34_Click()
    Dim testsql As String

    testsql = "INSERT INTO tblObservations (Site,TotalDepth) VALUES ('SUD-096',5)"
    With CurrentDb
        On Error GoTo Err_Execute
        .Execute testsql, dbFailOnError
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox ("Upload completed.  " & .RecordsAffected & " records added.")
    End With
    Exit Sub
    
Finish:
    Exit Sub
    
Err_Execute:
    If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For Each errLoop In DBEngine.Errors
            MsgBox ("Error number: " & errLoop.Number & vbCr & errLoop.Description)
        Next errLoop
    End If
    Resume Finish

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you used `DoCmd.SetWarnings = False` anywhere? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943753/adding-dbfailonerror-to-currentdb-execute-fails-to-update-table

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to your form code module's Declarations section and run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  What happens then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit`, like Hans said. Always use `Option Explicit`!

You're missing a reference to the Microsoft Office ##.# Access Database Engine object. This is where `dbFailOnError` is defined. Because you don't have that reference, `dbFailOnError` is not defined. This reference is added to all Access databases by default, and I strongly recommend adding it.

And because you're not using `Option Explicit`, VBA doesn't mind that it's undefined and just casts that undefined variable to a zero.

If, for some reason, you don't want to add the reference, use the [corresponding value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordsetoptionenum-enumeration-dao) for `dbFailOnError`:

```
.Execute testsql, 128
```